# Is it possible to find each story/post id using "inspect element" of browser

Tags: facebook

I am just looking to find a way to locate the unique id for each facebook post through browser `inspect element`.

So far the closest variable I found is `hyperfeed_story_id_562372813723813`. This is present with each story in `news feed` but when I share the same post on my timeline and look for this id, I can't find it.

Comment: Then Facebook is not putting the same id on them

Comment: yup, you're right, thanks for the help.